# Can't install RabbitMQ Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq

i'm trying to install into my project RabbitMq bundle
i use php7.4.9
i can install rabbitMQ server on Ubuntu, but now i have problem with Symfony

and I also wanted to ask, suddenly you came across a good example in OOP, I want to make good code

```
tanyaPC:  composer require php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle

Using version ^1.14 for php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.1.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle v1.14.4 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.7|^3.0|^4.0 -> no matching package found.
    - php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle v1.14.3 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.7|^3.0|^4.0 -> no matching package found.
    - php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle v1.14.2 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.7|^3.0|^4.0 -> no matching package found.
    - php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle v1.14.1 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.7|^3.0|^4.0 -> no matching package found.
    - php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle v1.14.0 requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.7|^3.0|^4.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle ^1.14 -> satisfiable by php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle[v1.14.0, v1.14.1, v1.14.2, v1.14.3, v1.14.4].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

i'm trying found resolve this problem in internet, but i didnt found, i really hope, that you can help me

this is my composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "^1.11",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.11",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "php-amqplib/php-amqplib": "^2.12",
        "symfony/console": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/validator": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.23",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "^5.1",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^5.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.1.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to install this library? Symfony doesn't need it, you should install `symfony/messenger`

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

It says it

```
requires symfony/dependency-injection ^2.7|^3.0|^4.0
```

but at the same time you have

```
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.1.*"
```

so it will not be compatible.

**Possible Solution 1**

You make all the Symfony stuff "old", something like

```
        "symfony/console": "^4.4.0|^5.0.0|^5.1.0",

    ...

    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.4.*"
        }
    }
```

(can probably be optimized), this might work.

**Possible Solution 2**

Since the bundle hasn't been updated in a while and you are using a new version of Symfony, a better way might be to use the [symfony/messenger](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html).

Comment: but symfony/messenger it is not rabbitMq

Comment: Check out https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/messenger and specifically https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/messenger/amqp to use RabbitMQ with Symfony's Messenger. The Messenger is the actual tool, RabbitMQ is one of the implementations / possibilities.

Comment: @Таня In 5.1 RabbitMQ support has been splitted into its own package, so you'll need to install [symfony/amqp-messenger](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/amqp-messenger) as well. There are also [some forks](https://packagist.org/packages/emag-tech-labs/rabbitmq-bundle) of the original bundle that have been updated to work with 5.x.